# random.random or random.choice for Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: python, montecarlo

I want to apply a simple Monte Carlo simulation on a variable that has three distinct values. Should I use `random.random` and assign the float to a variable value, or use `random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])`?

Comment: Why don't you try both and see which leads to the simplest, most readable code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a uniform distribution of these 3 values? If so, `random.choice` will give you exactly that.